# how can we select a required value from dropdown which dont have select tag or options tag using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

my html tag is something like this without select tag or options tag.
I want to select required dropdown value using selenium and java.
Can someone help me ?
since i cannot proceed with select, i cannot use it.
Finding it hard to select a value from the dropdown.

```
<div id="boundlist-1254" class="x-boundlist x-boundlist-floating x-layer x-boundlist-default x-border-box rp-floating rp-shadow-frame" tabindex="-1" style="right: auto; left: 642px; top: 245px; width: 215px; z-index: 19000; height: 287px;">
 <div id="boundlist-1254-listEl" class="x-boundlist-list-ct x-unselectable" role="presentation" style="overflow: auto; height: 287px;">
   <ul class="x-list-plain">
     <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option" unselectable="on">*Feb182015</li>
     <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option" unselectable="on">*ShaNili1</li>
     <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option" unselectable="on">1 test supplier</li>
     <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option" unselectable="on">3MTA3</li>
     <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option" unselectable="on">6060 Store Supplier</li>
     <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option" unselectable="on">7885 EL Supplier</li>
     <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option" unselectable="on">A new supplier</li>
     <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option" unselectable="on">A-Mamta-SUp</li>
     <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option" unselectable="on">ANHEUSER BUSCH-STOCKTON</li>
     <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option" unselectable="on">Aarti-MCLANE COMPANY</li>
     <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option" unselectable="on">AutoSupplier12</li>
     <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option" unselectable="on">BAY AREA DISTRIBUTING </li>
     <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option" unselectable="on">BON APPETIT </li>
```

Comment: Did you tried to `click()` on button to open drop-down and then `ckick()` on required option? Show code you've already used

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/40017443/2021160

Comment: here is the code, first of all i am trying to get list of elements inthe dropdown and then select the required one. 

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ext-gen1748']")).click();
     WebElement droplist = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='boundlist-1254-listEl']/ul"));
     
     List<WebElement> droplist_contents=droplist.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='boundlist-1254-listEl']/ul"));
     
     
     int index = droplist_contents.size();
     System.out.println(index);
It is always returning 1 since same xpath or css path is available for entire set

Comment: Anderson & Sai.. Required option i need to iterate, get from the dropdown and select it(i cannot use sendkeys as well)

Comment: (`here is the code` - do not comment comments requesting additional information or clarification: [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40362777/edit) the post. See [ASK].)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it using the below code
Dropdown will be scrolled down element by element until it finds and finally when it finds, it will select it.
I have passed xpath as object and value as data:

```
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    WebElement droplist = driver.findElement(By.xpath(object));
    List<WebElement> droplist_Contents = driver.findElements(By.xpath(object));
    int index = droplist_Contents.size();

    for (int count = 1; count <= index; count++) {

        //elemXPath: combining xpath with index value if the element
        String elemXPath= object+"["+count+"]";
        //content is the run time value of the dropdown value which moves one by one
        String content = driver.findElement(By.xpath(elemXPath)).getText();

        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                "arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(elemXPath)));

        if(content.equalsIgnoreCase(data)){
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(elemXPath)).click();
            break;
        }


    }
```