# I am not able to select country from Country Dropdown in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(countryDrpDwn));
        Actions act=new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement(countryDrpDwn).build().perform();
        countryDrpDwn.click();
```

This is the HTML List and please see the attachment:

```
    <li class="k-item" data-offset-index="225" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Tokelau</li>
    <li class="k-item" data-offset-index="226" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Tonga</li>
    <li class="k-item" data-offset-index="227" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Trinidad and Tobago</li>
    <li class="k-item" data-offset-index="228" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Tunisia</li>
    <li class="k-item" data-offset-index="229" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Turkey</li>
    <li class="k-item" data-offset-index="230" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Turkmenistan</li>
    <li class="k-item" data-offset-index="231" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Turks and Caicos Islands</li>
    <li class="k-item" data-offset-index="232" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Tuvalu</li>
    <li class="k-item" data-offset-index="233" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Uganda</li>
    <li class="k-item" data-offset-index="234" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Ukraine</li>
    <li class="k-item" data-offset-index="235" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">United Arab Emirates</li>
    <li class="k-item" data-offset-index="236" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland</li>
    <li class="k-item" data-offset-index="237" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">United States Minor Outlying Islands</li>
    <li class="k-item" data-offset-index="238" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">United States of America</li>
    <li class="k-item" data-offset-index="239" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Uruguay</li>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try adapting the solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40017443/2021160

Comment: You need to click once on the container element to open the dropdown and then again on the country you want selected.

Comment: @Sai I'll really appreciate that if you provide me the similar code.. this code you refer it's not working. actually, I can pull the list from the country list. but was not able to select the county.

Comment: JeffC I'll really appreciate that if you provide me the similar code.. this code you refer it's not working. actually, I can pull the list from the country list. but was not able to select the county.

Comment: Please paste the HTML snippet for the 'country' field. Along with any exception you get when you execute the code.

Comment: @Sai please see the image i just added.

Comment: Based on the images, the solution is available in the link provided earlier. The same principle applies here - all that was needed was for the xpaths to be changed. However, please see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the images provided, the Country Field is an `<input type="text">`. This typically indicates that the required text can directly be entered in the field using `sendKeys`. Sample code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='ddlPriCountry_input']")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='ddlPriCountry_input']")).sendKeys("Australia");
```

Further details can be found in the answer here: [How to perform dropdown in BMC Project using Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40017443/2021160)

The principle remains the same. What you need to do is identify xpaths to refer to the li tags. i.e if there is a specific need that mandates clicking on the drop down and selecting a value from the autocomplete list, then you perform the click, wait for the list to load and use the following xpath to click on a country:

```
//li[.='Australia']
```

**PS** Unless the application doesn't support it, I do not see a reason why you can't simply do a `sendKeys` to the element with the correct value

**Also,** in case there are issues with `clear()` and `sendKeys` you might need to click on the `input` first using this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='ddlPriCountry_input']")).click();
```